# What's the name of the <> operator?

Tags: elixir, computer-science

Out of curiosity: in Elixir how do we call the <> (binary concatenation) operator?

Comment: In Java we call it the diamond operator, but it has another meaning.

Comment: I just rephrased the question: I noted I'm actually curious as to if it has a "Elixir-specific" name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Binary Concatenation" Operator.

Sources:

1. [Elixir Documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html).
2. [Elixir Forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/whats-the-name-of-the-operator/1418/2).

Answer (score 1):

It's  often called diamond operator, especially in the Java world. You can also find it in perl.

You can also find it in other languages such as SQL, VBA or VisualBasic, but it has no special name there (it's just called `not equal` there). I suppose in Elixir it's just the `join operator`.

Comment: I'm also gonna change the question to ask if it has a "Elixir-specific" name (not sure if that makes sense though).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a specific name. I went through Programming Elixir book which didnt say it has a specific name as such. 
Its one of the **join operators** in elixir. Its concatenates two binaries.

Comment: Agreed. Just waiting to see if someone thinks differently (with sources/authority).